# Download link not working in modal

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, download

Morning, I've been having some problems by activating a download link for downloading a zip file, the download path is ok, but I can't figure out what it could be that is not allowing me to download the file, I've checked also in the forum but didn't work can you help me out fixing this?

Thanks in advance.

http://www.acidtrip.com.mx

It's the section with the  "participa" button, it should download but no luck.

Comment: When I open firebug, and click the link in the source-code directly, the download starts. I guess the event doesn't get triggered correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is, that your modal-dialog has an event-listener, which catches the click-event. 
So when you click on the button, you don't access the link.

You have to remove this event-listener, in order too make it work (it's on the `div`element with the id `#myModal`).

(If you disable javascript in your browser, the button works)

Answer (score 0):

Is your Download link responding to clicks?

if no, then try

using a div on the main page under the modal. write the click function using the modal

```
$('#divOutSideModal').off('click', '.YourDownloadLink');
$('#divOutSideModal').on('click', '.YourDownloadLink', function () {                    
   return false;
});
```